# Where to store data to be used for metrics? With the least performance / network impact in the back-end

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, backend, metrics

Let's say that I wanna keep track of the amount of **times** a service does "*something*".

I could store every single entry of that event in my database along some metadata about it, but if said event happens tens of times per second it would increase network latency / impact the application performance.

###### What would be a good way to track such data to be used in metrics?

Comment: You could use some real-time databases like Firebase Firestore wherein you could subscribe to a particular collection for metrics purposes. Whenever you add an event to the collection your metrics will automatically be updated in real-time.

Comment: Probably time-series database will keep your needs. For example [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-database) or  [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could log certain information that can later be used for analysis (using log4j or logback). I don't know what you are using for the back-end, but if you are using Spring or Play, this can be easily done.

In Spring you can implement a `HandlerInterceptor` or a filter that gets called for each endpoint (or only for specific ones, depending on your use case). You can use this listener to log the start timestamp, end timestamp, and other information like the endpoint that was called. Furthermore, you can store information in the ThreadContext to be used (for example, for calculating the time it took to process the request).

Similarly, for Play you can write a class that implements `play.http.ActionCreator` and add it to the processing flow (more on this here:  https://petrepopescu.tech/2021/09/intercepting-and-manipulating-requests-in-play-framework/ )

Now, you have the logs that have all the information needed and you can perform static analysis on it. You can have a job that parses the logs daily and offer the statistics. If you mark you logs properly (ex: by adding a keyword in the beginning of the message), parsing should be really easy.

If you DON'T want to do this because you need the stat near real-time, you will need to dedicate a thread just for this, if you want things to be as smooth for the user as possible. Maybe even have an `Actor` (see Akka Actors) that processes the data async. Again, using an Interceptor or a Filter, send a message to the actor (using `.tell()`, NOT `.ask()`) and it does the statistics and saves it in the database (or some other location of your choice).

Comment: Thanks, how do I give you the bounty points? I don't see an option :(

Comment: @Jsh0s https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Answer (score 1):

You can instrument your code to collect time-series metrics. Basically, maintain counters, and log/reset them at a time interval, like every 5 minutes. Then you can use other tools to collect and visualize those logs.

Take a look at [Spectator](https://github.com/Netflix/spectator).